# MongoDB: \lib\server.js:235 process.nextTick getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: mongodb

I'm a begginer in NodeJS and when i run `node MainApp.js` in console I get this error:

```
C:\Assigment 2 (NodeJS)\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:235
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND . .:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

I don't know what this means. Inside MainApp I connect mongoose: `mongoose.connect("./DataBase");` where DataBase is the folder where I run `mongod --dbpath "C:\[...]\DataBase`. The database server seems to start successfully, the console printing: `[...] waiting for connections on port 27017`.

server.js lines 231-236:

```
// Try to callback
      try {
        callback(err);
      } catch(err) {
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
      }
```

Package versions:
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "mongodb": "~2.1.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.3.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the whole process yet, but I hope this answer will provide some insight:

It seems that running `node` or `npm start` **without starting up the database** returns this error.

If **database is started**, then changing
`mongoose.connect("./DataBase");` (which previously caused the error)
to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database');`fixes the issue.

Intuitively this seems to simply be the error MongoDB returns when it can't find the database used by the server, however this might not be the precise description of the issue.

If someone can provide further insight into the problem, such help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

make sure that your database is up and running.
Go to your terminal and in your app directory run:

> mongod

Then restart your node server and you should be good go

Answer (score 0):

I changed connection string from mongodb://localhost:27017/ to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ and it worked.