# Thinkster MEAN Stack Tutorial giving me "node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236 process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })"

Tags: mongodb, curl, mean-stack

I am following the Thinkster MEAN Stack tutorial and am stuck at the [Testing the Initial Routes](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes) section in which, after I have already started the MongoDB using the command "**mongod &**" I still get this error when I npm start...

```
/Users/myname/workspace/mean_projects/flappernews/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
```

Now it seems as though that [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232766/mongodb-lib-server-js235-process-nexttick-getaddrinfo-enotfound-error) generally occurs when MongoDB is not started or not connected but I have used the

```
mongod &
```

command in my terminal like the tutorial suggested. How do I make sure that my app is connected to my local database on npm start and get past this error.

Here is how I setup the top portion of my app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
...
```

I believe the "**mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');**" part is what is giving me the error.

Comment: I usually just navigate to the directory where the mongodb exe files are stored, and run "mongod.exe" and then to confirm that everything is running correctly I run the mongo shell by using "mongo.exe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the mongodb service is not running on mac. I was never connected to the mongodb to begin with. I fixed the issue by running

```
brew services start mongodb
```

to connect to mongodb then running "**npm start**" on the terminal.

[Cannot connect to mongodb errno:61 Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418134/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-errno61-connection-refused)